# Location of source file #include <drivers/gpio.h>

Tags: c, zephyr-rtos

I am trying to find the source file used in an example program (push button interrupt).

I am not able to locate `drivers/gpio.h`

I thought this source file would be `~/zephyrproject/zephyr/drivers/gpio/`, but I am not seeing it there (see file list below)

Where can I find the `drivers/gpio.h` source code file on my machine?

Edit: It exists in github @ `~/zephyrproject/zephyr/drivers/gpio.h` , but not on my local machine, this is not clear

```
main.c

#include <zephyr.h>
#include <device.h>
#include <drivers/gpio.h> // where does this file live?
#include <sys/util.h>
#include <sys/printk.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
```

````
/* Folder Contents zephyr/drivers/gpio */

CMakeLists.txt          gpio_dw.h
Kconfig             gpio_dw_registers.h
Kconfig.andes_atcgpio100        gpio_emul.c
Kconfig.b91             gpio_eos_s3.c
Kconfig.cc13xx_cc26xx       gpio_esp32.c
Kconfig.cc32xx          gpio_fxl6408.c
Kconfig.cmsdk_ahb           gpio_gd32.c
Kconfig.creg_gpio           gpio_gecko.c
Kconfig.cy8c95xx            gpio_handlers.c
Kconfig.dw              gpio_imx.c
Kconfig.emul                gpio_intel.c
Kconfig.eos_s3          gpio_ite_it8xxx2.c
Kconfig.esp32           gpio_litex.c
Kconfig.fxl6408         gpio_lmp90xxx.c
Kconfig.gd32                gpio_lpc11u6x.c
Kconfig.gecko           gpio_mchp_xec.c
Kconfig.imx             gpio_mchp_xec_v2.c
Kconfig.intel               gpio_mcp230xx.c
Kconfig.it8xxx2         gpio_mcp23s17.c
Kconfig.litex               gpio_mcp23s17.h
Kconfig.lmp90xxx            gpio_mcp23sxx.c
Kconfig.lpc11u6x            gpio_mcp23xxx.c
Kconfig.mcp23s17            gpio_mcp23xxx.h
Kconfig.mcp23xxx            gpio_mcux.c
Kconfig.mcux            gpio_mcux_igpio.c
Kconfig.mcux_igpio          gpio_mcux_lpc.c
Kconfig.mcux_lpc            gpio_mmio32.c
Kconfig.mmio32          gpio_nct38xx.c
Kconfig.nct38xx         gpio_nct38xx.h
Kconfig.neorv32         gpio_nct38xx_alert.c
Kconfig.npcx                gpio_nct38xx_port.c
Kconfig.nrfx                gpio_neorv32.c
Kconfig.pca953x         gpio_npcx.c
Kconfig.pca95xx         gpio_nrfx.c
Kconfig.pcal6408a           gpio_pca953x.c
Kconfig.psoc6           gpio_pca95xx.c
Kconfig.rcar                gpio_pcal6408a.c
Kconfig.rpi_pico            gpio_psoc6.c
Kconfig.rv32m1          gpio_rcar.c
Kconfig.sam             gpio_rpi_pico.c
Kconfig.sam0            gpio_rv32m1.c
Kconfig.sifive              gpio_sam.c
Kconfig.stellaris           gpio_sam0.c
Kconfig.stm32           gpio_sam4l.c
Kconfig.stmpe1600           gpio_shell.c
Kconfig.sx1509b         gpio_sifive.c
Kconfig.test                gpio_stellaris.c
Kconfig.xec             gpio_stm32.c
Kconfig.xlnx                gpio_stm32.h
Kconfig.xlnx_ps         gpio_stmpe1600.c
gpio_andes_atcgpio100.c     gpio_sx1509b.c
gpio_b91.c              gpio_test.c
gpio_cc13xx_cc26xx.c        gpio_utils.h
gpio_cc32xx.c           gpio_xlnx_axi.c
gpio_cmsdk_ahb.c            gpio_xlnx_ps.c
gpio_cmsdk_ahb.h            gpio_xlnx_ps.h
gpio_creg_gpio.c            gpio_xlnx_ps_bank.c
gpio_cy8c95xx.c         gpio_xlnx_ps_bank.h
gpio_dw.c ```
````

Comment: `src file would be ~/zephyrproject/zephyr/drivers/gpio/` but it's `.h`, so it would be `...../drivers/gpio.h`

Comment: I don't quite follow, there are only folders under the ..../drivers folder, no files.  Do you have files in the ~zephyrproject/zephyr/drivers folder?

Comment: There is here https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/blob/main/include/zephyr/drivers/gpio.h

Answer (score 1):

In the folder *./zephyrproject/zephyr/drivers/gpio* is the source for each available MCU family. Instead of including one of these files, include the drivers API header *gpio.h*. The compiler will select the correct specific *gpio_YOURMCUFAMILY.h* file for you.

To include the GPIO driver in Zephyr e.g. v3.1 do:

```
#include <zephyr/drivers/gpio.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is inside the include directory i.e `zephyr\include\drivers\gpio.h`